# Why can ConcurrentHashMap elements also be trees

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I see that a ConcurrentHashMap stores its (key, value) pairs in [a list](https://github.com/daringyun/jdk10/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L784) of `Node`. However, a `Node` can also [be organised](https://github.com/daringyun/jdk10/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L2784) as a `TreeBin`.

So the underlying data structure of a ConcurrentHashMap is a list which has elements that are either standalone or trees.

Why isn't the data structure either a list or a tree?

What is the usefulness of this more complicated implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary tree structure allows for easy sorting of elements, either by their natural order, or by hash code if the items are not otherwise comparable.  For a rather large hash bucket, this allows for quick retrieval of elements.

In a smaller hash bucket, however, the cost of maintaining this tree is far greater than any savings that come from searching a tree structure.  In this case, a list will, on average, be more efficient.